# Rails notice using unobtrusive javascript

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I need write some unobtrusive javascript code to show the jquery gritter message.
I need to show it when I create a

```
<p id="notice"></p>
```

element in my page

This is the code to create te gritter dialog:

```
$.gritter.add({
    title: 'The title',
    text: notice text here...,
    class_name: 'gritter-success'
});
```

Comment: you could add the onload attribute to your p tag

Comment: the question is not clear enough...what exactly do you mean by "when I have notice to show", and "notice variable"

Comment: This "notice" variable is a Rails variable. The <%= notive %> will insert the contents of this variable in the page.

Comment: ... `text: $("#notice").innerHTML()` ?

Comment: I rewrite my question, to make it easier to understand.